# opencart Adding a custom menu in the header menu

Tags: php, opencart

This is a tricky problem that I am having.

I have a client / friend that wants on their open cart menu a button for home, which I was able to solve. However he wants a drop down menu for advice which holds 5 items. These 5 items are *Faq's*, *Contact us*, *Delivery Details*, *Privacy policy* and *Returns policy*.

Straight forward enough however the pages are *information* pages.

What I'd like to do is to link to these pages.

The ID of the advise is `80`

```php
            foreach ($children as $child) {
                if ($child['category_id'] == 80) {
                    $children_data[] = array(
                        'name' => $this->data['text_advicefaq'] = $this->language->get('text_advicefaq'),
                        'href' => $this->url->link('information/information', 'information_id=13')
                    );
                }

                $data = array(
                    'filter_category_id'  => $child['category_id'],
                    'filter_sub_category' => true
                );

                $product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($data);

                $children_data[] = array(
                    'name'  => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $product_total . ')' : ''),
                    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])
                );      
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like

## Step 1

Open file `catalog/view/theme/<your theme>/template/common/header.tpl`.

**Find** menu code.

**Add before** `</ul>` tag:

```php
      <li><a><?php echo $text_information; ?></a>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <?php foreach ($informations as $information) { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $information['href']; ?>"><?php echo $information['title']; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $contact; ?>"><?php echo $text_contact; ?></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
```

---

## Step 2

Open file `catalog/controller/common/header.php`.

**Find:**

```php
$this->data['text_checkout'] = $this->language->get('text_checkout');
```

**Add After:**

```php
$this->data['text_information'] = $this->language->get('text_information');
$this->data['text_contact'] = $this->language->get('text_contact');
```

---

## Step 3

In the same file `catalog/controller/common/header.php`

**Find:**

```php
    $this->data['checkout'] = $this->url->link('checkout/checkout', '', 'SSL');
```

**Add After:**

```php
    $this->load->model('catalog/information');
    $this->data['informations'] = array();
    foreach ($this->model_catalog_information->getInformations() as $result) {
        if ($result['bottom']) {
            $this->data['informations'][] = array(
                'title' => $result['title'],
                'href'  => $this->url->link('information/information', 'information_id=' . $result['information_id'])
            );
        }
    }
    $this->data['contact'] = $this->url->link('information/contact');
```

& then check it.