# Opencart 2.3 Adding a custom menu in header

Tags: php, menu, opencart

I'm trying to add a custom menu on the header of opencart 2.3, tried different options even tried this one from stack [opencart Adding a custom menu in the header menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24614528/opencart-adding-a-custom-menu-in-the-header-menu) 
But had no success, i found this code in Opencart forum it supposed to be placed in the header.php file:

```
$this->load->model('catalog/product');

$products_1 = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($data = array());                                           
if ($products_1) {$output = '<ul id="topnav">';}                                                            
foreach ($products_1 as $product_1) {                                                                           
    $output .= '<li>';                                                                                                                                          
    $unrewritten  = $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product_1['product_id']);                              
    $output .= '<a href="'.($unrewritten).'">' . $product_1['model'] . '</a>';                              
}
if ($products_1) {$output .= '</ul>';}                                                          
echo $output;                                                                   
?>
```

[And it shows me this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiWOk.png)

Comment: You want to load the model in controller file  and your above code is wrong. Opencart follow mvc pattren. So you need to call the model in the controller file and then make array in controller and using foreach you will display it on frontend.

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific, you'll need to edit the controller/common/header.php to include the variables that are undefined in the view/theme/(your theme)/common/header.tpl